# Which escape function to use when escaping an email or plain text?

Tags: plugins, sanitization, escaping

I have submitted a plugin to the WordPress repo, they have come back and said I need to escape the values in my email sending code NOT sanitize. So I'm confused what function they want me to use. Can you provide advice on the best escape  function I should use for an `email` and `plain text`?

Existing code they want me to escape and not sanitize:

```
$message = "
...
    <li><strong>Email:</strong> " . sanitize_email($_REQUEST['email']) . "</li>
    <li><strong>Name: </strong> " . sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['name'])  . "</li>
...
";

$emailResult =  wp_mail("foo@bar.com", "Support Request", $message, array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') );
```

There's no `esc_email()` or `esc_text()` function. So is the below correct to escape an email and plain text?

```
<li><strong>Email:</strong> " . esc_html($_REQUEST['email']) . "</li>
<li><strong>Name: </strong> " . esc_textarea($_REQUEST['name'])  . "</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can escape it as normal HTML, like so: 
`<?php echo esc_html( $email ); ?>`

For the mailto link, you can use esc_url. Just make sure you include *mailto:* into the URL, e.g.:
`<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'mailto:' . $email ); ?>">`

So a fully escaped mail link would look like this:
`<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'mailto:' . $email ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $email ); ?></a>`